# TypeScript Duplicate identifier in node_modules

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript and recently ran into an issue where type definitions in my `node_modules` directory are colliding.

Specifically, I am including both `@types/mocha` and `@types/jest`, and it's saying that there are duplicate type definitions for `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, etc.

I am using Webpack to bundle my code, and when I try to bundle it the TypeScript compiler emits a bunch of errors due to the duplicate definitions.

Note that I **am** excluding `node_modules` in my `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that setting `skipLibCheck: true` in my `tsconfig.json` file fixed this issue.